# Docker service starts in LXC but cannot execute commands

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, lxc

I have a software application that creates LinuX Containers as virtual hosts.  In these host(s), I want to start the docker service and run it.

So I initialize the lxc and open up a terminal.  I enter `service docker start` and get the message `* Starting Docker: docker [OK]`

When I type any docker command, for example `docker info` I get the error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///va/run/docker.sock.  Is the docker daemon running?`

I have not seen anyone with the same issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using **sudo**?

Comment: Using `sudo docker info` returns `sudo: unable to resolve in host n1: Resource temporarily unavailable` I believe this is because I am running it in a linux container.

Comment: Typo in some config?  `unix:///va**r**/run/docker.sock` ...

Comment: I'm not even sure what type of file `docker.sock` is.  Its not a directory, its not a file.  When I go to the `/var/run/` folder and type `ls -l` it appears as `docker.sock=`  I should also note that I don't have this issue running docker from the actual host (as opposed to the lxc)